# git: set custom merge behaviour for specific remote and/or remote branches

Tags: git, github, merge, git-config, git-merge-conflict

I'm working on a project that is intended to be cloned on GitHub for proper usage. It's also intended to be easily usable and configurable for people that aren't savvy in git.

Essentially, there is a directory in the project that is designed to have custom files on a clone by clone basis (`./app/assets/`) and I'd like to make it so that when a person who has cloned the project pulls changes from the origin project then it doesn't overwrite/merge anything in this file.

From what I've been reading, the way to make a project merge files between branches in this way is to set up a custom merge driver (what I've been looking at is detailed [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b)) but this doesn't seem robust enough to do exactly what I want.

I'm looking to be able to have those files be merged normally between branches from whatever remote is the "my-clone" remote, but when branches from the original project (probably named "origin" from my understanding) are merged into someone elses "my-clone" copy of the project then I want the merge to automatically ignore any conflicting or additonal files from the `./app/assets` directory of the origin branch, even though they're tracked and recorded in the repo.

Ideally, I'd like the solution to be trackable in the repo so that solution is present by default in the repo. If that's not possible, then a solution which could be scripted to be run by people who clone the app would also be sufficient. Ideas and learning opportunities to help me solve this are much appreciated!

[Link to Project](https://github.com/Sqash/artist-base)